# ORA 6502 character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am a newbie in PL/SQL

I have an PL SQL. And im getting an error shown in the title. ORA 6502 character string buffer too small.

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE MailSender IS
tmpVar VARCHAR2(2048);
BEGIN
FOR cur_rec IN 
   (SELECT * FROM dom_email1 where rownum <= 50 and eto is not null ORDER BY eid asc)
   LOOP
   tmpVar := ltrim(cur_rec.ETO, ' ; ');
   tmpVar := rtrim(tmpVar, '; ');
   tmpVar := rtrim(tmpVar, ' ');

   DOMSYS_EMAIL.SEND_EMAIL(msg_from => 'noreply@gmail.com'
                                       , msg_tos => tmpVar
                                       , msg_subject => cur_rec.SUBJ
                                       , msg_text => cur_rec.MSG
                                       , mailhost => '10.63.17.38'); 

   UPDATE DOM_EMAIL1 SET eid='1' WHERE eid= cur_rec.EID;
END LOOP;


DELETE FROM DOM_EMAIL1 WHERE eid='1';

EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   NULL;
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
   RAISE;
END MailSender;
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  You have a variable declares, probably tmpVar, and you are trying to assign a string value to it greater than 2048 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is due to the size is not satisfied for any of the below variables/cursor value you are passing in your procedure

- tmpVar
- cur_rec.SUBJ
- cur_rec.MSG

Add the below line in your procedure before send mail (DOMSYS_EMAIL.SEND_EMAIL) to validate the size of each value you passed and check whether it satisfies the parameter size limit of the DOMSYS_EMAIL.SEND_EMAIL procedure

> dbms_output.put_line('tmpVar :' || length(tmpVar) ||' - '|| 'cur_rec.SUBJ :'|| length(cur_rec.SUBJ) ||' - '|| 'cur_rec.MSG :' || length(cur_rec.MSG));

For varchar2,you can update the size limit if required after validation

Comment: "Max size limit is 4000 in 11g and 32767 for 12c". That's not true. 4000 limit is set for SQL Engine and 32767 for PL/SQL engine. And this limit is the same both in 11g and 12c.